# Address in mailbox given does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, swiftmailer

## Sending mail to multiple users.

```php
 $users=a:3:{i:0;s:14:"uday@email.com";i:1;s:14:"guru@email.com";i:2;N;}
    $usermail=unserialize($users);
    $usermail=json_encode($usermail);
            Mail::to($usermail)
                ->send(new MeetingInvite($meeting,$usermail));
```

> Problem is in `to()` method when I pass static value `to(['uday@email.com','guru@email.com'])` it worked.

#### Problem is I have data in  `unserialized` format. How to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found an error in the array. Last value of the array is Null.
>
> ### And Removing whitespace solved the problem by using `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue due to  0 width spaces in several email addresses.
I had to add the following code snippet to avoid this kind of error.

```
str_replace("\xE2\x80\x8B", "", $mail);
```

I hope it's could help you.